# SQLAlchemy: Inconsistent behaviour after commit

Tags: python, session, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy ORM, whose `__str__()` function prints a table of keys and values.
The following code commits it to the DB and prints it (attribute names changed for clarity):

```
user.some_attribute = <Some integer>
session.add(user)
session.commit()
app.logger.debug("some_attribute is %s" % user.some_attribute)
app.logger.debug("Created a DB row:\n%s" % user)
```

**The crazy thing here is that the second debug print only works if the first debug exists!**

In other words, if the two debug lines exist, I get:

```
some_attribute is 5
+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Field                                    | Value                                           |
+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| creation_time                            | 2016-09-26 15:25:45.630230                      |
| description                              | Test Poly 835                                   |
| destination_truck_ids                    | ['A']                                             |
| future_event_series_id                   | None                                            |
| id                                       | 1017                                            |
...
```

But if only the second one is present, I get:

```
+-------+-------+
| Field | Value |
+-------+-------+
+-------+-------+
```

**Why does the ORM have no attributes, unless one of its features is printed?**

Comment: How did you get `__str__` to generate all that anyway? In my case, `str(user)` is what I always expected: `<__main__.User object at 0x0000000003866FD0>`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, even though I'm not really sure about the nature of the problem.

Quoting [the manual](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.commit):

> By default, the Session also expires all database loaded state on all
>   ORM-managed attributes after transaction commit. This so that
>   subsequent operations load the most recent data from the database.
>   This behavior can be disabled using the expire_on_commit=False option
>   to sessionmaker or the Session constructor.

If I load the session with `expire_on_commit=False`, the problem is solved - I get the ORM even after the commit.

Comment: This is not a workaround; it's the correct solution IMO. If you need access to an instance's attributes after you commit without loading it again, turn off `expire_on_commit`. This feature is on by default, I believe, because it make naive code work. If you know what you are doing, you can simply turn it off.

Comment: That's agreeable, except for the fact that printing one ORM attributes causes it to re-appear.